# How to fix PgAgent stuck on "r" on batch step errors?

Tags: postgresql, pgagent

On windows (10,11 and windows server 2022).
With PostgreSQL 14 and 15.

Pgagent is running as a service.

[image]

It runs SQL jobs and access pgpass correctly to run jobs as Local on multiple DBs.
It also execute batch files correctly.

**BUT if the batch files called in the step does not exists, the job fail (as expected) but the step hangs in an "r" state.**

Job log:
[image: The job]
Step log:
[image: The step]

The expected behavior is that it return as status "f", result "1" and output "path to file does not exist"
On another vm, with pg10, It works as intended like below:
[image: Expected result]
The "r" state is not an effect of PgAgent crashing.
The service keeps running.(To be noted that the service crash if I run another agent that crashes whether it is SQL or Batch)

**Anyone had that issue and managed to fix it ?**

EDIT :
The postgresql log points to the encoding. It is in french and the accents aren't handled.
*`2023-05-31 17:08:05.928 CEST [16000] ERREUR:  sÃ©quence d'octets invalide pour l'encodage Â« UTF8 Â» : 0x82`*

Answer (score 0):

The answer was there :https://stackoverflow.com/a/71948417

The older vm/pg10 was running on windows server 2012 so the issue never arised.

Both solutions work : [image: Windows 10 / Windows server 2016 or later: Beta: Use Unicode UTF-8]

Comment: It would be infinitely better if you replaced that image with the text.